# Accessing live value of a DOM element

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden input that has a default value, which can be changed depending on the value of the selected radio button associated with it.

So, if I select the second radio button, the js_file_path hidden input will have its value changed to "/shared". Nice and easy, and I've got this to work fine.

My problem is when I try to get js_file_path's value via jQuery `$("#js_file_path").val()`, I always get the value of the hidden field when the page was loaded. How do I get its current value instead? I know of the live() handler and its purpose, but not quite sure how to make use of it in this context where I'm trying to pass "js_file_path"'s value as a function argument.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the code to detect the value of the file path has changed.

```
<input type="hidden" id="js_local_file_path" value="local">
<input type="hidden" id="js_shared_file_path" value="shared">
<input type="radio" name="js_type_for_file_upload" value="local" checked>
<input type="radio" name="js_type_for_file_upload" value="shared">
<input type="hidden" id="js_file_path" value="local">

$("[name=js_type_for_file_upload]").live( "change", function(){
    switch( $(this).val() ){
        case "local":
            $("#js_file_path").val( $("#js_local_file_path").val() );
            // do other stuff
        break;
        case "shared": 
           $("#js_file_path").val( $("#js_shared_file_path").val() );
            // do other stuff
        break;
    }
});`
```

So, when I select the second radio button and check the DOM I can see that the js_file_path's value has been changed to "shared" correctly.

I then try to proceed and make a function call that includes the value of js_file_path as its argument when a button with an id "button" is clicked.

```
$("#button").click( function(){ 
     a_name_of_a_function( $("#js_file_path").val() ); 
});
```

For debugging, I put an alert prompt inside a_name_of_a_function() to output its file_path's parameter's value.

```
function a_name_of_a_function( file_path ){
    alert( file_path );
    // other stuff
}
```

Even if I've selected the "shared" radio button, the alert prompt will always displays "local".

Comment: How do you know that the value of `js_file_path` is actually changed? I would say that `$("#js_file_path").val()` remaining its initial value is a good clue that your code for changing `js_file_path` is not working.

Comment: Agreed with @Ray Baxter. Can you post the jQuery code in question?

Comment: I know via a change event handler attached to the radio button whose name attribute is called, "js_type_for_file_upload". I've updated the original post to include it. I've inspected the DOM using Chrome, and the value does change correctly when the radio button's value is changed.

Comment: Your code doesn't match the posted html.  Your radio button name is `js_type` but in the code you have `js_type_for_file_upload`.  Your switch has `local` and `shared` but the radio button values are `/local/` and `/shared/`

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I was just streamlining the names used initially to make it easier to follow. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try changing $("#button").click to $("#button").live("click",

Answer (score 0):

Based off your example HTML, you shouldn't even need to do a switch:

```
$("input[name=js_type]").live( "change", function(){
    $("#js_file_path").val( $(this).val() );
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/2JrWM/2/ -- I simply changed the hidden field to a text field so you could see it in action without looking at the console.

EDIT: This is the updated code on the fiddle. Works fine:

```
$("input[name=js_type_for_file_upload]").live( "change", function(){
    $("#js_file_path").val( $(this).val());

});

$('#button').live('click',function(){
    alert($("#js_file_path").val());
});
```

Comment: True based on the switch statement the above is sufficient. However, again for the purpose of streamlining the code paste, I removed irrelevant lines of code found in each of the switch's case.

Comment: Removing "irrelevant lines of code" is making us have to fire in the wind bro. Regardless the code works so simply apply it to your application, switch or not :)

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated the original post again for a more clear idea about my code and its structure. Your code definitely works, but it's not what I'm looking for unfortunately; my bad due to the unclear contradictory nature of my originally pasted code.

Comment: I don't see any html in your edits which shows an element with the id="js_shared_file_path"

Comment: Okay added now. Examining the code I've put on this page, I can see a potential easy workaround where I simply pass the value of the radio button as the function's argument instead of the value of the hidden file_path input. In any case, I'm still VERY curious as to how I'd be able to pass the actual live value of the file_path hidden input as a function argument.